# Getting 3rd object from json array

Tags: javascript, json, colors, setting

I have an array in json that looks like this:

```
[ 
  {"x":161,"y":109,"colour":"FF0000"},
  {"x":146,"y":93, "colour":"FF0000"},
  {"x":133,"y":81, "colour":"FF0000"} 
];
```

I want to set a `strokeStyle` property to get a colour from the objects given.

So how can I select the "colour" value?

Comment: its impossible to answer this question unless u specify the language u are working on

Comment: woops, i need to call it in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript lets you access attributes in JSON objects pretty easily. For example, you could iterate through this particular object and `console.log()` out the colour with this loop (assuming jsonObj is the variable storing the given JSON array):

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++){
    console.log(jsonObj[i].colour);
}
```

(If you weren't looking to iterate through them, and just wanted a specific object, you could just use a numerical index instead of an iterator with a loop.)

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9UdLW/). (Remember to open the console log in order to see the results.)

If this isn't what you were looking for, feel free to let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
//data is your array
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
    // use can access the colour field like this:
    console.log(element.colour); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Use foreach**

```
data.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry.colour);
});
```

**2. For loop**

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].colour);
}
```

**3. Use for-in**

```
for (entry in data) {
    console.log(entry.colour);
}
```